# How to get the node name of the selection in tiny mce?

Tags: tinymce

I want to check the node name of the selection. I have tried using getStart() and getNode(), but both fail for me. I have an element say "H1", if user selects some text and apply styles, code checks if the node is "H1". If it is and the whole text has not been selected, the selection is wrapped  inside a span and styles are applied to the span. But, after loosing the selection, if I select the previously stylized text, by mouse, or by double clicking, following lines return H1 many times and only few times it returns span. How can find the exact node name ?

```
 var thisNode=tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getNode().nodeName;
 var thisNode=tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getStart().nodeName;
```

Comment: works perferctly for me (Firefox)

Comment: can you give some more information

Comment: I think it was cache problem...Will update if same thing happens .

Comment: what happened to oyur other SO account?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
tinymce.init({
mode : "specific_textareas",
theme: "modern",
selector: 'textarea',
editor_selector :"mceEditor", 
setup:function(editor){
  editor.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
   console.log(editor.selection.getNode().nodeName)
  });
}});
```